# How can I change the size of an NSView when autolayout is active?

Tags: cocoa, resize, nsview, autolayout

I have a `NSViewController` with an attached view defined in a `xib`. Everything is done properly (at least I hope), so that when I change the height of the view, all the subviews stay properly organized.

I want to change the height of the view programmatically. Basically, one of the subviews of my view is an `NSTextView` and when there is a lot of text inside, I want to enlarge the view.

If I change the `frame.size` of the view, nothing happens, because of the auto layout I think.

**Is there a standard way to change the height (or the width) of the view in such a context ?**

---

EDIT : 
I have added a constraint to the view : I "pined" its `height`.
Then, I have added this constraint as an `IBOutlet` property.
Thus, I can change the `.constant` value of the constraint.

Comment: Try setting `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of your views superview to NO, before changing `.constant`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new constraint for the view : "pin" its height.
2. Register this constraint as an `IBOutlet` property.
3. You can access the constraint and `.constant` value of it to change the size of your view.